# Why was my I'd and question deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I posted [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/138629/reduction-of-alkynes-to-trans-alkene-using-lialh4?noredirect=1#comment272551_138629) here few hours ago, but my question and my I'd was blatantly deleted, I also posted one [question earlier](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/137118/isolation-of-tautomers-which-are-in-good-proportions) anonymously, however that question was also deleted. Can the mods provide a reasonable answer to me?[image]

Also I request mods to reduce my suspension period, it's already quite a few months. I promise not to inflate my reputations again.

Comment: What was the question about? Only those above 10000 rep can see what you have shared

Comment: @Safdar LAH reducing alkynes to trans alkanes, on which you provided two links.

Comment: Make maybe a screenshot of the question, can't access the link,

Comment: The question was not the reason. I can vouch for that.

Comment: @OS my I'd was too deleted, I can't see either..

Comment: Why were you banned in the first place Zenix?

Comment: @Safdar cause I used another account and upvoted my *9* questions/answers. I did that on two earlier occasions too :(

Comment: Anyway, did you get the answer to your question? the LAH one..

Comment: Well, that does make it hard to trust you .. Can you use other SE sites or is it just on Chem SE?

Comment: @Safdar according to your links, ig, book is correct. Just on Chem :)

Comment: "I used another account and upvoted my 9 questions/answers" You shouldn't do that. That's just greediness from your part. You will get rep. points from posting question and answering question. This is not a competition of "who will get more rep. points?" Work diligently and mutually and you will earn both respect and reputation. Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 8):

Creating a sock puppet to evade your [suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) and post while you are suspended is a violation of Stack Exchange rules.

If moderators find evidence of ban evasion, they may unceremoniously delete the sock puppet account.

Comment: If that's one of the rule of Stack Exchange, I won't blame you. Thanks, and is there any chance of reduction of suspension time period?